# If nonnegative $f\in C^{\infty}[0,\delta)$ with $f(0)=...=f^{(k)}(0)=0$ and $f^{(k+1)}(0)>0$, proof that $f^{1/k}\in C^{\infty}[0,\delta)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If nonnegative $f\in C^{\infty}[0,\delta)$ with $f(0)=...=f^{(k-1)}(0)=0$ and $f^{(k)}(0)>0$, and $f|_{(0,\delta)}>0$, prove that $f^{1/k}\in C^{\infty}[0,\delta)$.

---

By definition, $$(f^{1/k})'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{f^{1/k}(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\left(\frac{\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^{k}+o(x^{k})}{x^k}\right)^{1/k}=\left(\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\right)^{1/k}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}(f^{1/k})'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{k}\frac{f'(x)}{f^{1-1/k}(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{k}\frac{\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{(k-1)!}x^{k-1}+o(x^{k-1})}{[\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^{k}+o(x^{k})]^{1-1/k}}=\left(\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\right)^{1/k}$$

so $f^{1/k}\in C^{1}[0,\delta)$, but I don't have any idea to prove $f$ is smooth (perhaps needs inverse function theorem). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused: is $\delta$ a fixed number?  Or are we saying we can choose a $\delta$ small enough (depending on $f$) that $f^{1/k} \in C^\infty[0,\delta)$?

Comment: In particular, if $\delta$ is fixed independent and $f$ is only required to be nonnegative, then this is not true (and in fact, $f^{1/k}$ doesn't even need to be $C^1$!)

Comment: @Strants Sir, could you tell me why does $f^{1/k}$ need not to be $C^1$? I think that $f\in C^{\infty}(0,\delta)$ and $x^{1/k}\in C^{\infty}(0,\delta)$, so the composition $f^{1/k}\in C^{\infty}(0,\delta)$.

Comment: You need $x^{1/k}$ to be $C^\infty$ on the *range* of $f$ to apply the chain rule and get $f^{1/k}$ in $C^\infty$.  But, notice that $x^{1/k}$ is not even differentiable at $0$, so there is no hope of using this strategy if $f(x)$ is ever equal to $0$!

Comment: @Strants Yes you are right, I have modifies my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution from P. D. Miller's *Applied Asymptotic Analysis*.

Consider
$$F(s,v)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(sv)}{s^k} -1& s> 0 \\
\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}v^k-1 &s=0
\end{cases}
$$
so that $F(s,v)=\sum_{m=k}^n \frac{f^{(m)}(0)}{m!}s^{m-k}v^m-1+O(s^{n+1}v^{n+1})$ which is infinitely differentiable, and $$F(0,v_*)=F\left(0,\left(\frac{k!}{f^{(k)}(0)}\right)^{1/k}\right)=0$$$$F_v(0,v_*)=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{(k-1)!}v_*^{k-1}> 0$$
by implict  function theorem, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $v=v(s)\in C^{\infty}[0,\epsilon)$ and $f(sv(s))=s^k$. Let $x(s)=sv(s)\in C^{\infty}[0,\epsilon)$, $x'(0)=v(0)=v_*>0$, by inverse function theorem, we have $s=s(x)$ such that $$f(x)=s(x)^k$$
implies $s(x)=f(x)^{1/k}$ is infinitely differentiable.